# Android build fails only in TeamCity server

Tags: android, android-studio, mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using TeamCity as my CI server.When I run a build for an android studio project it is failing.
 But when I open the cloned repository in Android Studio in the build server itself it gives a successful build. Please help me out..

**EDIT::**

When the checkout directory from TeamCity is opened in Android Studio it is also failing.So I guess the issue is with the checkout from TeamCIty.

Comment: I guess, that Android Studio and TeamCity build runner might use different versions. Does build log say anything about that?

Comment: @Malvin I couldn't understand about what version you are telling..is it the jdk

Comment: @Malvin: Managed to find the solution myself.The answer is posted below.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to get an answer to my own question.Some files were kept in the `.hgignore` folder as a result of which it did not get checked out during TeamCity build.Removing those from the `.hgignore` folder solved the problem for me.